# SSH Remote Connection - dsa keys are no longer used? Then what should I do?

Tags: ssh

I already put my IP address to the `/etc/hosts.allow` and checked if fail2ban banned my IP Address. I also checked if the sshd_config file's MaxStartups are too small but it isn't.
When I checked,

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log`
I can see the line Connection reset by XXX.XXX.X.XXX port 3000 [preauth].

But in my laptop(client) the connection is immediately stopped with the message kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer.

Can somebody please help me with this? I've spent a good three hours on this…

+) `ssh -vvv` shows as below:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3 \
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config \
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for * \
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XXX.XXX.XX.XX is address \
debug2: ssh_connect_direct \
debug1: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XX.XX [XXX.XXX.XX.XX] port 22. \
debug1: Connection established. \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_rsa type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_xmss type -1 \
debug1: identity file /Users/sueyeon/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1 \
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1 \
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

+) Someone told me
**dsa keys (e.g. id_dsa) are no longer used by ssh (due to compromise of the dsa encryption scheme). Your server may receive the key and automatically close the connection.**

What is the solution for this?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and my laptop(client) is macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Create a new key, with i.e. `ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t ed25519`. See [the OpenSSH releasenotes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html) for deprecations

Comment: Also, try clearing out the `id_rsa` and `id_dsa` files (backing them up somewhere first just in case of course). It's possible that the remote host is cutting you off because you're making too many bad authentication attempts before you even get to a key it'll accept.

Comment: @Shadur Thanks a lot for the suggestions, but neither worked for me. Do you guys have any other ideas?

Comment: If you have a way to access the server at all, log into it and configure `sshd` for maximum verbosity, then check its logs as well while you try to connect.

Comment: You probably don't even need to reconfigure `sshd` initially; just look at its log output where it gives a reason for the refusal